issues with proxy_fcgi timeoutissue
We have a front end backend web app that I do not understand and the developers are no longer contactable. the error message I get in
ssl_error_log
 [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1695:tid 139887973996288] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.240.132:60433] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)

there also seems to be and issue with a "socket"
[Mon Nov 04 11:07:31.865028 2024] [proxy:error] [pid 3759:tid 140098641016576] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed

that file does exist just unsure what it does.
the error on the browser side is a gateway timeout so I know apache web server is installed and I assume this php_fpm is doing some kind of proxy
any ideas on what might be happening?
